# Lazy loading on mat|r

Tags: mobile

I have the next code for a simple app on mat|r project.

```
Experience NewsObject{
    String title as Label
    String author as Label
    String image as Image
}

Entry Experience ListNews{
    Decision button action("rules.getNews") label("Get News")
    Array<NewsObject> news as List
    Decision getMoreNews action("rules.getNews") label("Get More News")
}

RuleContext rules{

    Rule getNews{
        ListNews ln = broker.ui.getDataSource()
        ln.news = service.latestNews.call()
    }

    Rule openNews{
        ListNews ln = broker.ui.getDataSource()
        Integer index = ln.news.selected().get(0)
        broker.ui.push("NewsObject",ln.news.get(index))

    }
}
```

The line: ln.news = service.latestNews.call(), call a service that have a limit and skip parameters, How can I get new results when the scroll reaches the end of viewport? this is posible on mat|r? some ideas for this? maybe with a button that load new data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with mat|r you can't implement the lazy loading pattern.

The solution would be to create a button below the list component to add new results when the user arrives there. This button should call a rule, that calls the service with a parameter that varies according to the number of elements that are already loaded in the list component.